# Eclipse I can't link project B to project A

Tags: java, eclipse, project, addition

I work with Eclipse. I have two projects in the workspace. This is my Eclipse navigator.

[image]

I want to add AR04.CME to cmeWeb.

Folder cmeShare has some jar which I need in cmeWeb.

I click in cmeWeb properties ->Java Build Path -> Projects

This is the screen

[image]

AR04.CME doesn't appear as project.

How can I add this project?

Comment: i think there is a property in project "Is Library" you need to enable it for `AR04.CME`

Comment: _AR04.CME_ must be a Java project. Add a project to the build path of another project means extend the build path by another build path, so both projects must be Java projects (otherwise they will not have a build path).

Answer (score 0):

Linking Project A to another Project B is useful when you have `source code` in A that you want to share to B. That's not your case. You don't seem to share source code, but a *compiled library* instead.

Your best option is to edit cmeWeb's Build Classpath > libraries > add jar > select your Jar library.